# Div alignment side by side height issue

Tags: css, html, height, responsive-design

I am laying out product images inside a div using:

```
<div>
        <img src="imgs/1.jpg" />
        <h3>Flowers Bunch</h3>
        <span>Rs 500</span>
</div>
```

These divs are having float set to left, so they align side by side depending upon width that is available. So there could be 2, 3, or 4 products getting displayed side by side in a row.

The issue is if one of the div takes more height than others in the same row, then on the next row, the space below the div whose height got extended isn't being used and remains empty. How to  solve the issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution (just using fixed heights would probably be the easiest) is to use something like [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), with the end result looking something like this:

[image]

Comment: There's also isotope, which is probably a better solution, but you have to pay for a commercial license. Masonry's pretty cool tho

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1) You can set a min-height for the elements, if you are sure they won't be higher than that value.

2) You can use a div with **position: relative; overflow: hidden;** for each row

3) You can make a clearfix element and to add it after each row.

```
.clearfix { clear: both; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: 9999; }
```